# Replace string based on dictionary pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pandas, pyspark

New to pyspark, I'd like to replace string from column based on a dictionary.

Below is a sample list with special characters (the real one contains names)

```
lists = ['.', ',', '*', '+', '-', '_', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', ';', ':', '/', '|', '<', '>', '^', '$', '#', '@', '!', '?', '~', '"', '\'', '´', '`', ' ', '\.\.', '&']

dic_name = {}
for element in lists:
    dic_name[element] = ' '
```

That's what I've tried so far without any results

```
# Replace key by Value
for key, value in dic_name.items():
    df = df.withColumn('Name_Clean', regexp_replace('Name', key, value))
```

In Pandas, I was able to do something like this:
df[col] = df[col].str.replace(key, value, regex=True)

Below is the df

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "#2A"), (2, "&PIM"),], ["id", "Name"])

| id|Name|
+---+----+
|  1| #2A|
|  2|&PIM|
```

Expected output after applying function

```
| id|Name|Name_Clean|
+---+----+----+
|  1| #2A|2A|
|  2|&PIM|PIM|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dict items and construct the column expression and then use it in `withColumn`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "#2A"), (2, "&PIM"), (3, "&PIM#*][]"), (4, """.,*+-_(){}[];:/|<>^$#@!?~"\'´` \\.\\.&""") ], ["id", "Name"])

lists = ['.', ',', '*', '+', '-', '_', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', ';', ':', '/', '|', '<', '>', '^', '$', '#', '@', '!', '?', '~', '"', '\'', '´', '`', ' ', '\.\.', '&']
dic_name = {}
for element in lists:
    dic_name[element] = ' '

# Construct Replacement Expression

replacement_expr = col("Name")

for k, v in dic_name.items():
    replacement_expr = regexp_replace(replacement_expr, f"[\{k}]", v)

df.withColumn("Name_Clean", replacement_expr).show(truncate=False)

"""
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id |Name                               |Name_Clean                         |
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|1  |#2A                                | 2A                                |
|2  |&PIM                               | PIM                               |
|3  |&PIM#*][]                          | PIM                               |
|4  |.,*+-_(){}[];:/|<>^$#@!?~"'´` \.\.&|                                   |
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
"""
```

If your replacement value is same for matching expressions then the following logic would be better.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "#2A"), (2, "&PIM"), (3, "&PIM#*][]"), (4, """.,*+-_(){}[];:/|<>^$#@!?~"\'´` \\.\\.&""") ], ["id", "Name"])

lists = ['.', ',', '*', '+', '-', '_', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', ';', ':', '/', '|', '<', '>', '^', '$', '#', '@', '!', '?', '~', '"', '\'', '´', '`', ' ', '\.\.', '&']

from functools import reduce
expr = reduce(lambda a, x: f"{a} | \{x}", lists)
regex_expr = f"[{expr}]"

df.withColumn("Name_Clean", regexp_replace(col("Name"), regex_expr, " ")).show(truncate=False)

"""
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id |Name                               |Name_Clean                         |
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|1  |#2A                                | 2A                                |
|2  |&PIM                               | PIM                               |
|3  |&PIM#*][]                          | PIM                               |
|4  |.,*+-_(){}[];:/|<>^$#@!?~"'´` \.\.&|                                   |
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
"""
```