# Use dictionary as part of replace_regexp in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I am trying to use a dictionary like this:

```
mydictionary = {'AL':'Alabama', '(AL)': 'Alabama', 'WI':'Wisconsin','GA': 'Georgia','(GA)': 'Georgia'}
```

To go through a spark dataframe:

```
data = [{"ID": 1, "TheString": "On WI ! On WI !"},
            {"ID": 2, "TheString": "The state of AL is next to GA"},
            {"ID": 3, "TheString": "The state of (AL) is also next to (GA)"},        
            {"ID": 4, "TheString": "Alabama is in the South"},
            {"ID": 5, "TheString": 'Wisconsin is up north way'}
            ]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data)
display(sdf)
```

And replace the substring found in the value part of the dictionary with matching substrings to the key.

So, something like this:

```
for k, v in mydictionary.items():
    replacement_expr = regexp_replace(col("TheString"), '(\s+)'+k, v)
    print(replacement_expr)
                      
sdf.withColumn("TheString_New", replacement_expr).show(truncate=False)
```

(this of course does not work; the regular expression being compiled is wrong)
A few things to note:
The abbreviation has either a space before and after, or left and right parentheses.
I think the big problem here is that I can't get the re to "compile" correctly across the dictionary elements.  (And then also throw in the "space or parentheses" restriction noted.)
I realize I could get rid of the (`GA`) with parentheses keys (and just use GA with spaces or parentheses as boundaries), but it seemed simpler to have those cases in the dictionary.

Expected result:

```
On Wisconsin ! On Wisconsin !
The state of Alabama is next to Georgia
The state of (Alabama) is next to (Georgia)
Alabama is in the South
Wisconsin is way up north
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Some close solutions I've looked at:
[Replace string based on dictionary pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620068/replace-string-based-on-dictionary-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` in regex to specify word boundary. Also, you can use `functools.reduce` to generate the replace expression from the dict itemps like this:

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F,


replace_expr = reduce(
    lambda a, b: F.regexp_replace(a, rf"\b{b[0]}\b", b[1]),
    mydictionary.items(),
    F.col("TheString")
)

sdf.withColumn("TheString", replace_expr).show(truncate=False)

# +---+------------------------------------------------+
# |ID |TheString                                       |
# +---+------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |On Wisconsin ! On Wisconsin !                   |
# |2  |The state of Alabama is next to Georgia         |
# |3  |The state of (Alabama) is also next to (Georgia)|
# |4  |Alabama is in the South                         |
# |5  |Wisconsin is up north way                       |
# +---+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Ding ding.  We have a winner. Very nice and efficient.  Thanks.